# Epoll и посылка данных из стороннего потока

Tags: c++, linux, epoll

Продолжаю биться над проблемой с epoll и посылкой из стороннего потока.

Логика работы: Добавляю сокет в епул `epoll_ctl()` с флагами `EPOLLIN | EPOLLOUT | EPOLLONESHOT`. Так как epoll_wait() вызывается из нескольких потоков используется флаг `EPOLLONESHOT`, указывающий на то, что сокет нужно отдать только один раз.

При получении сокета из epoll_wait() происходит чтение и отправка данных. После чего снова вызывается `epoll_ctl()`. Если никакие данные не отправляются, в `epoll_ctl()` не ставится флаг EPOLLOUT, иначе сокет снова будет получен из epoll_wait(). И пока все работает в плоскости epoll() - обработчик, все работает замечательно.

Но появляется задача написать прокси, это значит, что в из обработчика одного сокета нужно послать данные в другой сокет. И данные даже посылаются, до тех пор, пока `send()` не говорит, что в буфере больше нет места. Тогда я сохраняю данные в свой буфер, привязанный к сокету в который надо послать эти данные.

И тут возникает проблема. Данные в буфере, сокет в епуле, с большой вероятностью с флагами: `EPOLLIN | EPOLLONESHOT`, и, не собирается оттуда выходить. Как его вытащить в обработчик?

Причем желательно сделать это потокобезопасно. Можно вызвать для сокета `epoll_ctl()`, но, если он в этот момент выйдет из `epoll_wait()`, появляется шанс, что он будет выдан из `epoll_wait()` второй раз, после чего программа упадет.

Возможно есть способ что-то сделать с сокетом, чтобы епул отреагировал? Или как вообще реализуется подобная работа в прокси?

Comment: Как-то сложновато у Вас все это выглядит. С epoll_wait в одном потоке не получается? А еще лучше вообще все в одном потоке делать.

Comment: Если делать все в одном потоке, то это будет не многопоточный сервер, а непонятно что. Оно как бы и делается в одном потоке с epoll_wait(), но таких потоков несколько. Сложно оно начинает выглядеть при попытке проксирования данных из одного сокета в другой. Мне тоже это не нравится и хочется найти способ упростить логику.

Comment: Не представляя задачу в целом и спроектированную под нее архитектуру сложно что-то конкретное посоветовать. / Ну, если "проксируемых" сокетов мало, то может быть стоит делать 2 thread-а  для каждого такого соединения (в каждом thread будут просто синхронные read/write в одном в одну сторону. а в другом в другую, вообще без epoll_wait  в них. Тут все получится "самосинхронизируемым"). / Если хотите обсудить подробно "опубликуйте" свои спецификации.

Comment: В каком виде должна быть спецификация? Я постарался в вопросе описать всю логику работы.  В сервере по умолчанию 15 рабочих потоков, создавать дополнительные потоки или подвешивать эти - это костыли. Задача сделать шустрый и оптимальный сервер иначе не стоило бы заниматься.

Comment: Не знаю даже, как лучше "публиковать". Может в каком-нибудь "расшареном" пастебине? (а то ведь тут сразу теперь прикроют). А тут ссылку. По количеству комментариев нам скоро тут предложат сделать чат-room, вот там можно обсуждать. А тут, наверное, краткое описание сервера (это что web-server? Вы то знаете, а все остальные могут только догадываться). Именно 15 потоков, это как-то странно выглядит. Наверное слышали такую штуку -- *в программировании есть только 3 понятия -- один, два и много*. А описали Вы не логику работы, а какой-то частный кусочек реализации. Но, продолжим уже в понедельник.

Comment: Ну в принципе это и есть логика, когда сокет болтается между епулом и обработчиком. К сожалению продолжить я смогу лишь во вторник, через неделю. Думаю к этому времени определюсь с выкладыванием, а быть может и с проблемой что придумаю.